# Maximal Ideals in Tensor product of Algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, maximal-and-prime-ideals, tensor-decomposition

Let A, B be algebras over algebraically  closed field $\mathbb F$, and m be a maximal ideal in $A\otimes_\mathbb{F} B$ such that $A\otimes_\mathbb{F} B/m \cong \mathbb F$. Show that there are maximal ideals $a\subset A, b\subset B$ such that $m = a\otimes B + A\otimes b$.

Is this also true when m, a, b are prime ideals rather than maximal?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that the isomorphism in $(A\otimes_\mathbb{F} B)/m \cong \mathbb F$
means an isomorphism of $\Bbb F$-algebras.

Your condition means that $m$ is the kernel of a $\Bbb F$-homomorphism
$\phi:A\otimes B\to\Bbb F$. Such a homomorphism comes from a pair
of $\Bbb F$-homomorphisms $\phi_1:A\to\Bbb F$ and $\phi_2:B\to\Bbb F$ and
where
$$\phi(x\otimes y)=\phi_1(x)\otimes\phi_2(y).$$
Let $a$ and $b$ be the kernels of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$.

For your second question, I presume you no longer
want $(A\otimes_\mathbb{F} B)/m \cong \mathbb F$ since that necessitates
the maximality of $m$. If so, consider the example $A=\Bbb F[X]$, $B=\Bbb F[Y]$
and $m=\left<X\otimes Y-1\right>$.

Comment: @raman.james That's a "exercise for the reader". You could show that (i) the RHS is contained in $\ker\phi$ and (ii) the RHS is maximal.

Comment: Yeah, in the second case we want to drop the requirement that $(A\otimes_\mathbb{F}B)/m \cong \mathbb  F$ as you point out. I thought a little bit about the example you provide. So, here's how I thought about  it. By way of contradiction assume that there are prime $a, b$ such that $a\otimes B + b\otimes A = \langle x\otimes y - 1\rangle$ then we would have a factorisation of 1 in terms of x, y, which isn't possible. I realise that at this point I'm hand waving, but am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Yeah for sure. Thanks for the hint. I managed to prove it successfully :)

Comment: Wait, I'm not so sure actually. All the rings here are PIDs right? And every prime ideal in a PID is maximal, so shouldn't the first part tell us that this should hold for prime ideals too?

Comment: $F[X]\otimes_F F[Y]$ is not a PID.